# Difference between src and background for image view

Tags: android, imageview

I have two imageviews. I have set background for one image view and I have set src for one image view . But both are looking differnt and also when i press the imageview with background set it is not showing the selection. can anyone explain why this happens ?

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"     
    android:background="@drawable/perm_group_camera"/>
```

[image]

```
<ImageButton android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/perm_group_calendar"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But both are looking differnt

First, the drawables are different.

Second, the background always scales to the size of the view.

> when i press the imageview with background set it is not showing the selection. can anyone explain why this happens

The selection effect is because by default, the background is a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) with a different appearance in `state_pressed`. Your custom background looks the same in all states. You can create `StateListDrawables` in xml with a [`selector`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Answer (score 0):

`Background` will fill all avaliable place of view, `src` - will paste image and scale/positioning using ImageView parameters. For example, parameters "scaleType", "scaleX", "scaleY", "gravity", "adjustViewBounds" will affects only on `src` image

Comment: why when the imaeview (with background set) is not showing the selection when i pressed.