# Replacing an ImageView Image Correctly

Tags: java, android

I am currently making an android application that is Hangman and i need to update my ImageView with every time the user guesses a letter that is not in the phrase but it updates oddly, it doesn't delete the old photo and replace it, it just add's a new one to the screen and not in the same boundaries that the old photo was set to. Here's my code.

Java to replace the photo:

```
    ImageView hangmanPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hangmanPhoto);
    //This updates the loss counter
    pictureEnumerator++;
    //This set's the photo
    if(pictureEnumerator==1){
        hangmanPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangman_1);
    }
    else if(pictureEnumerator==2){
        hangmanPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangman_2);
    }
    else if(pictureEnumerator==3){
        hangmanPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangman_3);
    }
    else if(pictureEnumerator==4){
        hangmanPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangman_4);
    }
    else if(pictureEnumerator==5){
        hangmanPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.hangman_5);
    }
    else if(pictureEnumerator==6){
        hangmanPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.gameend);
    }
```

And this is how i have the base image once my app starts:

`<ImageView>
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/hangmanPhoto"
      android:background="@drawable/hangman_0"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:paddingBottom="40dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.51"
      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
      android:padding="20dp"
      android:paddingRight="20dp" />`

Here's the screen:

[image: This is my screen when it happens.]

Comment: replace your imageView xml with <ImageView>
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/hangmanPhoto"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:paddingBottom="40dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"
      android:paddingLeft="20dp"
      android:paddingRight="20dp" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use src instead background in your Xml file and in your Java too

```
android:background="@drawable/hangman_0"
```

To

```
android:src="@drawable/hangman_0"
```

see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352322/difference-between-src-and-background-for-image-view)